# Unable to share global variable between threads with flask

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, module

### Context

I'm trying to write a python flask server that answers a simple request. The data to be returned in the response is queried from a backend service. Since this query may take some time to complete, I don't want to do it synchronously, I want to have it run periodically, in a background thread, where I can explicitly control the frequency. It should update some data structure that is shared with the flask view function, so the GET requests gets its answer from the shared data.

I'm including two sample codes below. In both codes, `cnt` is a global variable, starting at 0, and increased inside a separate thread. The `index.html` file displays the value of `cnt`:

```
<h1>cnt = {{ cnt }}</h1>
```

### The issue I'm facing

When the view function is inside the same module, it works: every time I refresh the page with F5, the value of `cnt` has changed, I can see it increasing.

But when I put the view functions in a separate `routes` module (which I import at the end of my `hello.py` file), it no longer works: I can see in the server traces that `cnt` is being increased by the background thread, but when I refresh the page I always see

```
cnt = 1
```

It's as if I now have two different copies of the `cnt` variable, even though the variable has been imported into the `routes` module.

#### Note

I've found countless question on SO on this topic, but none that really addresses this specific concern. Also, I'm perfectly aware that in my examples below, there is no *lock* protecting the shared data (which is a simple `cnt` variable) and I'm not handling *thread termination*. This is being deliberately ignored for now, in order to keep the sample code minimal.

Here are the codes.

### Single module, it works

Here's the main `hello.py` file, with everything inside the same module:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import threading as th
from time import sleep

cnt = 0

app = Flask(__name__)

# Run in background thread
def do_stuff():
    global cnt
    while True:
        cnt += 1
        print(f'do_stuff: cnt={cnt}')
        sleep(1)

# Create the separate thread
t = th.Thread(target=do_stuff)
t.start()

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html', cnt=cnt)
```

The variable is indeed shared between the background thread and the view function, as expected.

### Separate modules, it no longer works

Here's the main `hello.py` module, without the view function :

```
from flask import Flask
import threading as th
from time import sleep

cnt = 0

app = Flask(__name__)

# Run in background thread
def do_stuff():
    global cnt
    while True:
        cnt += 1
        print(f'do_stuff: cnt={cnt}')
        sleep(1)

# Create the separate thread
t = th.Thread(target=do_stuff)
t.start()

import routes
```

And here is the separate `routes.py` file (see import at the end of `hello.py` above):

```
# routes.py

from hello import app, cnt 
from flask import render_template

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html', cnt=cnt)
```

With this code, the web page always displays `cnt = 1`, as if the two modules had two distinct instances of the `cnt`variable.

I feel like I'm missing some basic insight into python modules, or threads, or their interaction. Any help will be appreciated, and my apologies for such a long question.

Comment: globals are generally not shared between modules ... but you should be able to `import moduleB;moduleB.count += 1`

Comment: I'm importing the other way around, I define and increment the variable in one module (`hello.py`), then I import it into the other one (`routes.py`) with `from hello import app, cnt`. Shouldn't this work as well ?

Comment: only if you access it as `moduleA.count`  if you import it .. all you have imported is a number which is non-mutable (ie changing the variable doesn't change references) ... but if you `import moduleA` that is mutable ... so when you access `moduleA.count`  its the reference to the count in moduleA

Comment: I also tried putting `cnt` inside a `common.py` module, and importing that into the other two modules, but then it was the background thread that was no longer incrementing the variable, it was always 0.

Comment: thats the same problem ... you imported a non-mutable number ... instead `import common`  which is a mutable module ... and then changes can reflect through to other things accessing `common.count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

globals are not shared between modules

when you say

`from moduleA import count`  you have imported a non mutable number

if something in another file changes count in module A it will not update anything else... its overwritten that count you imported with a new variable named count effectively

if **count** was a mutable object than any changes would indeed reflect back ... so if it was a list or dictionary or a class with fields etc..

instead you can import the module which is mutable

`import moduleA`

now when moduleA changes count it is changing the mutable module field and you can see it in another place by printing `moduleA.count`

Comment: I think it's not accurate to say `you have imported a non mutable number` you can try to make cnt a list and apped to it and the list will change in the second file. it's more correct to say that we are importing the reference or the pointer to the object at that time and since ints are immutable adding to it will give you a new object with different address in memory

Comment: I never realized there was this difference... I always preferred `from moduleA import cnt` because then I could avoid prefixing all the references to `cnt`, I thought it made the code less cluttered. Now I totally get the difference, thx.